# Insert a scale bar into a map using R

Tags: r, dictionary, insert, scale

I am using the map.scale function from the library(maps) to add a scale bar; however, it is very difficult to manipulate its position and dimensions, specially if I am working with different sites that required a scale bar to indicate their overall area.

Is there a quick way to insert a scale bar in a specific location of the plot (map)?

Comment: Do you mean something more quick than using x and y arguments in map.scale()?

Comment: With a single map it is easier to place the scale according to X/Y positions; however, when I generate multiple maps that are not always in the same grid (X/Y coordinates) this can be a very slow process. I was wondering if you could place the scale in specific locations of the plot region (top corner, bottom/center, right top corner, etc).

Comment: Wherever I plot the scale, it always says `location of scale out of this world!`. I am confused about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the grconvertX and grconvertY values should do it for you.

```
map.scale(grconvertX(0.5,"npc"), grconvertY(0.08, "npc"),col="#0000ffff", metric = FALSE, ratio=FALSE, relwidth=0.2)
```